# How to assign a matlab value to a linux variable?

Tags: bash, scripts, matlab

I am running Matlab through linux terminal. At first I execute a .sh file from the terminal. At some point it opens Matlab and after running a .m script i need a certain value assigned to a matlab variable to be assigned to a linux variable back to the running shell. Can this be done? 
I thought to write this value to a .txt file but i don't know the linux command to read the file and assign the value to a variable.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the variable value from Matlab to a file and then read the value into a bash variable. Assuming the file 'data.txt' holds the value

```
X=$(cat data.txt)
```

will read the value from the file into the variable X.